# Finding Birth Parents of Child from New England in 1850s?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, adoption, massachusetts, connecticut

Ella Louisa Fuller, born 16 February 1850, was adopted by Hiram Fuller and his wife Emilie Louise Delaplaine.

I'm not sure when the adoption occurred, but they had been living in Halifax, MA, and moved to the Fairfield, CT area, so the adoption could have occurred in either place (or somewhere else).

How might I find the birth parents of Ella Louisa Fuller?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to always ask a single focussed question.  What evidence do you have that Ella was born on 16 Feb 1850?  What evidence do you have that she was adopted by Hiram Fuller and his wife Emilie Louise Delaplaine?